# simple xpath not working to find a node

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Iam trying to get a particular node with value equals my input parameter,my xpath is like this where b is the node I need

```
string xpath = "/Batches/Measurement/Batch[market=someval]/b";

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Batches>
  <Measurement>
    <Batch>
      <market>someval</market>
      <b>someval</b>
    </Batch>
  </Measurement>
</Batches>

var xmlNode = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(xpath);
```

no nodes retruned always count 0 ,I checked that the xmldoc is loaded properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your xpath is nearly perfect. Only keep in mind const values have to be put in apostrophe:

```
"/Batches/Measurement/Batch[market='someval']/b"
```

Update: C# code example:

```
 XmlNodeList nodeList;
 nodeList = root.SelectNodes("/Batches/Measurement/Batch[market='someval']/b");
  foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
  {
      for (int i = 0; i < node.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
      {
          Console.WriteLine(node.ChildNodes[i].InnerText);
      }       
  }
```

The return value of SelectNodes is a nodeList. You have to iterate through it.

And a little bit shorter:

```
      XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
      string text;
      text = root.SelectSingleNode("/Batches/Measurement/Batch[market='someval']/b").InnerText;
      Console.WriteLine(text);
```

Comment: Thanks @hr_117 your solution works but one problem if I use "/Batches/Measurement/Batch[market='someval']" then one node gets selected ,but if I use "/Batches/Measurement/Batch[market='someval']/b" nothing gets returned actually I need the value of b node

Comment: Should I not use Selectnodes if I need to select b value?

Comment: Thanks much for ur update I tried it but no values returned in the node list if I use /b in the xpath if I don't use /b I get the value of the market node which is someval,i really don't know how to proceed or debug ...

Comment: ya I know but I don't know why 0 is returned always I changed the xmldoc with market as attribute ( a lot of changes to make in xml but cannot think of any other way) ,so I can select with @market='someval' and then get the b node innertext ,it works fine.thanks for helping,marking this as answer since it helped me come closer to result.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using LINQ to XML?

It is slightly more efficient and shorter clearner syntax for selecting. I know you asked about Xpath so feel free to ignore this. Just making you aware of the option

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("c:\\tmp\\test.xml");
var result = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Element("b") != null)
   .Select(x => x.Element("b").Value);
```

Comment: XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(filepath);
var result = xDoc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Element("market").Value == "someval")
              .Select(x => x.Element("b").Value);                                     thanks for helping tried urs as well but alwys returns null ,finally got the answer by rewriting the xml doc with market as attribute

Comment: weird, extracts it here using your xml. Good you got it sorted